# How do I get a value with a hidden input type using python 3?

Tags: python, python-3.x, beautifulsoup

I am trying to get the value of a hidden input type. Even though it is empty now the value is generated later. I get the error "TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not subscriptable" when I run my code.

This is the code on the website:

```
< input type="hidden" id="bb_device_id" name="bb_device_id" value="" >
```

I am using the following code to try and get the value:

```
deviceId = soup.find('input', {'id': 'bb_device_id'})['value']
```

Comment: What is `soup`? I know it is probably a `BeautifulSoup`, but you did not post enough code to know for sure. Please see [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and provide a [minimal, complete, and verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Yes sorry soup is Beautiful soup

Comment: @BeauBridges As I mentioned earlier, you'll need to provide a [minimal, complete, and verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). No one can help you with the tiny bit of code you have posted.

Comment: create minimal working example so everyone could run it and test solutions. And you could add url to page.

Comment: I tried your HTML with your `find()` and had no problem. You have to show real page - there can be different problem, ie. code in `<iframe>` or elements added by JavaScript.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not subscriptable" generally means that you are trying to index into `None`. In general, we say that an object is subscriptable if you can index it as with lists: `l[1]` meaning the second element of the object l. Most objects are not subscriptable; `None` is not for obvious reasons.

Anyways, this means `soup.find('input', {'id': 'bb_device_id'})` is returning `None`.

I would suggest trying `soup.find(id='bb_device_id'})` and seeing if it also returns `None`; if so, there might be a problem with your document, i.e. it doesn't contain what you think it contains.